# How to pickle function from imported module with dill

Tags: pickle, dill

I'm trying to pickle functions with dill. I want to include the whole function and not just a reference to it. Here are my two files:

fun.py:

```
import dill
from foo import ppp

def qqq(me):
    return me + 1

print(dill.dumps(ppp, protocol=4, recurse=True, byref=True))
print(dill.dumps(qqq, protocol=4, recurse=True, byref=True))
```

And foo.py

```
def qqq(me):
    return me + 1
```

When I run fun.py I get the following output:

```
b'\x80\x04\x95\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x03foo\x94\x8c\x03ppp\x94\x93\x94.'
b'\x80\x04\x95\x90\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\ndill._dill\x94\x8c\x10_create_function\x94\x93\x94(h\x00\x8c\n_load_type\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x08CodeType\x94\x85\x94R\x94(K\x01K\x00K\x01K\x02KCC\x08|\x00d\x01\x17\x00S\x00\x94NK\x01\x86\x94)\x8c\x02me\x94\x85\x94\x8c\x06fun.py\x94\x8c\x03qqq\x94K\x04C\x02\x00\x01\x94))t\x94R\x94}\x94h\rNN}\x94Nt\x94R\x94.'
```

I want to be able to make the first line of output be more similar to the second line, and actually encapsulate the function without the need for a context when reloaded later. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks so much!
James

Answer (score 0):

If the module (`foo`) is installed on both computers, then there should be no need to do anything but import the function.  So, I'll assume the question is in regard to a module that is only installed on the first machine.

It also depends on whether the module `foo` is "installed" on `sys.path` or is just available in the current directory.  See:
https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/123

If it's only available in the current directory, either use `dill` to pickle the file itself or use something like `dill.source.getsource` to extract the source of the module as a string, and then transfer the string as a "pickle" (this is what `ppft` does).

Generally, however, `dill` pickles imported functions by reference, and thus assumes they are available on both sides of the `load`/`dump`.

Comment: I think dill.source.getsource is what I want! I want to create a hash of the source code (or whatever is transferred to the remote machine) so that I can deterministically cache the output at a location based on the instructions. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what function needs to be called on the server side to execute the source code outputted by getsource?

Comment: IF I remember correctly, `dill.source.importable` uses `getsource` to get an importable object... so you'd just need to write the string to a file (or buffer), then import it.  The other suggestion I had was to look into `ppft`, which does a lot of this for you (and doesn't rely on writing to disk).  If `pfft` is too low-level to digest, there's a high-level interface within `pathos.parallel` https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/blob/master/pathos/parallel.py